# Time zone display formatting in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using `moment.js` to get the date from my cordova application.

**expected output**

2017-06-04T10:17:00+0530

**Current output**

2017-06-04T10:17:00+05:30

**Code**

```
var date=moment(enddate).format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ")
console.log(date);
```

So how can i get the date as  `2017-06-04T10:17:00+0530` this format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ZZ` instead of `Z` for the time zone ([from the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/))

```
var date=moment(enddate).format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZZ")
                                                     ^
```